# Org mode flashes indentation of lines with parentheses

Tags: org-mode, indentation, evil, balanced-parentheses

I've been having some issues using org-mode with paren matching. Here are a few screenshots of the problem. In short, when my mouse isn't on a line, the line is shown correctly, but when parenthesis are being highlighted the line drops to the minimum indentation. W/o paren highlighting this problem isn't there, but I wanted to keep that in org mode.

[image: correctly indented]

[image: indentation dropped]

Note, this happens only on the last line (but this is a problem, as that is the line i'm usually editing).

Comment: What are those numbers going on in the left of the screenshot -- is that relative line numbers or something like that?

Comment: Yah, I have the linum-relative-mode package from melpa installed.

Comment: Does your problem go away if you disable `linum-relative-mode`?

Comment: Turning off linum-mode, linum-relative-mode, and evil-mode doesn't help. Do you think one of my plugins is causing the problem? I could try disabling them one by one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, there was an org update which fixed this issue. If you run into this issue, I would reccomend pulling the latest org from elpa (9.x), which resolved this issue completely for me. On 8.10.x, this issue is reduced, but still happens occasionally.